# Criando arquivo JSON com PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou trazendo dados do BD que serão usados como `Values` das `Keys` do meu novo `file.json` que estou tentando criar. As `Keys` estão sendo lidas de um arquivo JSON já existente.

Então, basicamente o que preciso fazer é um arquivo igual ao existente, porém, com os valores diferentes.
O formato é mais ou menos assim:

```
 //Abro arquivo já existente
 $myFile  = fopen($fileName, "r") or die("Unable to open the file !");
 //Content possui o conteúdo do meu arquivo
 $content = json_decode(fread($myFile, filesize($fileName)));
 fclose($myFile); //Fecha arquivo

 foreach( $content as $keys => $value ) {         

    foreach( $value as $key) {
       //....
    }
 }
```

O formato é mais ou menos assim:

```
{
    "title1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
     },
     "title2": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"      
     },
}
```

Com o loop mostrado acima, já consigo percorrer todas as `Keys` de cada `Title` (desconheço nome correto).

Gostaria de ajuda na lógica para montar o novo arquivo com o que eu tenho agora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o `&` comercial no `foreach` (chamado de referencia), deve ficar assim:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "title1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    "title2": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"      
    }
}';

$decodificado = json_decode($json);

if (!$decodificado) {
    die('JSON invalido');
}

//$title pega o title1 e title2, title3, etc
foreach ($decodificado as $keyTitle => &$title) {

    //$value pega o valor key1, key3, key3, key4, etc
    foreach ($title as $key => &$value) {

        //Aqui um exemplo para alterar as chaves com nome key2 e key3 apenas
        if ($key === 'key2') {
            $value = rand(0, 100);
        } elseif ($key === 'key3') {
            $value = rand(200, 300);
        }
    }
}

print_r($decodificado);
```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/sSml1W

---

Note que se você souber exatamente qual o local da chave você pode simplesmente setar o objeto, por exemplo, supondo que queira alterar:

- key2 dentro de title1
- key1 dentro de title2
- key3 dentro de title2

Então você deve fazer assim:

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "title1": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    "title2": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"      
    }
}';

$decodificado = json_decode($json);

if (!$decodificado) {
    die('JSON invalido');
}

$decodificado->title1->key2 = 'Novo valor FOO';
$decodificado->title2->key1 = 'Novo valor BAR';
$decodificado->title2->key3 = 'Novo valor BAZ';

print_r($decodificado);
```

Exemplo no IDEONE: https://ideone.com/bvFxkV

---

Então sabendo o nome das chaves que deseja alterar depois é só usar o `json_encode` e salvar novamente em um arquivo (ou aonde desejar), por exemplo:

```
...

$codificado = json_encode($decodificado);

file_put_contents('novo.json', $codificado);
```

Comment: Show. Tem como identificar se a próxima iteração no loop existirá ou não ? Trabalhando com JSon não consegui acesso a nenhum tipo de `index`, apenas os valores das chaves.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro no loop eu criei a var `$keyTitle` que se refere ao title1, title2, etc e a var `$key` eu criei pra detectar se é key1, key2, etc, desta forma vc pode saber em que chave esta exatamente e mudar conforme a necessidade, supondo que queira mudar o `key53` que esteja dentro do `title22` bastaria fazer um if assim `if ($keyTitle == 'title22' && $key == 'key52') { $value = 'NOVO VALOR';  }`, então o truque é usar as IFs ;)